# Load a Bean with database table values and make it cacheable with JPA 2nd level cache

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink

I need to cache my database records into my application and use it across the entire application. I do not understand how to make my entity class cacheable. Somewhere I read that we need to commit in order to make the entity class cacheable, but in my case I have pre stored config data in database, which may change very rarely and we are not persisting it from our class.

I am posting my code below which I tried to achieve the above requirement.

Here is my bean class:

```
@Entity(name="ActCodeMetadataBean")
@Table(name="ACT_CODE_MTDT")
@Cacheable(true)
public class ActCodeMetadataBean {



    @Id
    private String ACT_CODE;
    private String PRDT_ID;
    private String ACT_ACTN;
    private String ACT_EXEC_ORDR;
    private String RQST_STRC_ID;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date CRTN_DATE;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date LAST_UPDT_DATE;

 public ActCodeMetadataBean() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

public String getACT_CODE() {
    return ACT_CODE;
}

public void setACT_CODE(String aCT_CODE) {
    ACT_CODE = aCT_CODE;
}

public String getPRDT_ID() {
    return PRDT_ID;
}

public void setPRDT_ID(String pRDT_ID) {
    PRDT_ID = pRDT_ID;
}

public String getACT_ACTN() {
    return ACT_ACTN;
}

public void setACT_ACTN(String aCT_ACTN) {
    ACT_ACTN = aCT_ACTN;
}

public String getACT_EXEC_ORDR() {
    return ACT_EXEC_ORDR;
}

public void setACT_EXEC_ORDR(String aCT_EXEC_ORDR) {
    ACT_EXEC_ORDR = aCT_EXEC_ORDR;
}

public String getRQST_STRC_ID() {
    return RQST_STRC_ID;
}

public void setRQST_STRC_ID(String rQST_STRC_ID) {
    RQST_STRC_ID = rQST_STRC_ID;
}

public Date getCRTN_DATE() {
    return CRTN_DATE;
}

public void setCRTN_DATE(Date cRTN_DATE) {
    CRTN_DATE = cRTN_DATE;
}

public Date getLAST_UPDT_DATE() {
    return LAST_UPDT_DATE;
}

public void setLAST_UPDT_DATE(Date lAST_UPDT_DATE) {
    LAST_UPDT_DATE = lAST_UPDT_DATE;
}


public ActCodeMetadataBean(String aCT_CODE, String pRDT_ID,
        String aCT_ACTN, String aCT_EXEC_ORDR, String rQST_STRC_ID,
        Date cRTN_DATE, Date lAST_UPDT_DATE) {
    super();
    ACT_CODE = aCT_CODE;
    PRDT_ID = pRDT_ID;
    ACT_ACTN = aCT_ACTN;
    ACT_EXEC_ORDR = aCT_EXEC_ORDR;
    RQST_STRC_ID = rQST_STRC_ID;
    CRTN_DATE = cRTN_DATE;
    LAST_UPDT_DATE = lAST_UPDT_DATE;
}


}
```

And my persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="OMSDemo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>com.airtel.oms.entity.ProvisioningInterface</class>
    <class>com.airtel.oms.entity.ProvisioningTask</class>


    <!-- Cache classes -->
    <class>com.airtel.cache.ActCodeMetadataBean</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orclaq"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="artl"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="artl"/>
             <property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ALL"/>
        </properties>

  </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

and here is the main:

class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("OMSDemo");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    manager.setProperty("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.USE);
    Query query = (Query) manager.createNativeQuery("select * from ACT_CODE_MTDT", ActCodeMetadataBean.class);
    query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", 
            CacheStoreMode.USE);
    ActCodeMetadataBean account=null;
    List<Object> results = query.getResultList();
    for(Object e : results)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
   Cache cache = factory.getCache();

    // cache.
    System.out.println("cache.contain should return true: "+cache.contains(ActCodeMetadataBean.class, account.getACT_CODE()));
    cache.evict(ActCodeMetadataBean.class);
    System.out.println("cache.contain should return false: "+cache.contains(ActCodeMetadataBean.class, account.getACT_CODE()));
    manager.close();
    factory.close();
}
```

}
:

[Here is the orcle table which i need to cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w065n.png)

Here is the response:

```
cache.contain should return true: false
cache.contain should return false: false
```

What can I do to achieve it?

Comment: What results did you get back from your query, and the code you've shown should get an NPE as  account=null and never set anywhere else.  Please note that your query will populate the EntityManager cache.  Try using a JPQL query outside a transaction rather then a native query as it can use the shared cache to build results.

Comment: Yes, Chris you are true actually got the NPE but i revered it to new operator now, and also did few changes i am getting true for the cache.contains now. thanks for the advice